# Получить данные dict с html страницы (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Не знаю как используя Nokogiri можно получить данные dataLayer:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hill's Ideal Balance-IB Snack Pollo y Manzana</title> <script data-    keepinline="true">/* datalayer */
dataLayer = [];
dataLayer.push({"pageCategory":"product","ecommerce":{"currencyCode":"EUR","detail":{"products":[{"name":"IB Snack Pollo y Manzana","id":"6161v9343","price":"4.65","brand":"Hills Ideal Balance ","category":"Snacks Naturales para Perro","variant":"1 Sobre 227 gr"}]}},"google_tag_params":{"ecomm_pagetype":"product","ecomm_prodid":"6161v9343","ecomm_totalvalue":4.6500000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625,"ecomm_category":"Snacks Naturales para Perro"}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы наверное как-то криво скопировали сюда пример вашей страницы, потому что очевидно, что это Javascript, хотя он не находится внутри `<script>`. При помощи Nokogiri вы доберетесь до содержимого тега `<script>`, а далее отпарсите при помощи гема rkelly, как я это сделал здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52158957/322020